# Please tell me how and where we will define "addEventListener"

Tags: javascript, html

Please tell me how and where we will define "addEventListener"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function doSomething() {
    alert('Image clicked');
  }

var myImage = document.getElementById('my_image_id');
myImage.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);

</script>
```

HTML------------------------------------

```
<body>
  <img src="xxx.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="="my_image_id"/>
</body>
```

I'm getting an error `myImage` is `null` or `not an object`.

Comment: id="="my_image_id" is this a typo..?

Comment: Syntax error `id="="`. Also make sure you add the script **after** the markup.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it inside `window.onload` to wait for the DOM fully loaded before attaching your event listener. Also notice that `addEventListener` does not work across all browsers. To make it work across all browsers, try:

```
window.onload = function()
{
  var myImage = document.getElementById('my_image_id');
  if (myImage.addEventListener){
    myImage.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
  } else if (myImage.attachEvent){
       myImage.attachEvent('onclick', doSomething);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yeah you are right. Thanks, if we put the above code anywhere, it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

You should put your code after your markup, or wrap your code with a function and execute function when document is ready.

The reason you get the error is that, when document.getElementById('my_image_id'); called, there is no element with given id that time. I hope you got the idea.

Comment: ok got it, hope i can add multiple addeventlistners and removeevent listners can u give me an example?

Comment: @Sujesh: Just call `addEventListener` multiple times.

Comment: @FelixKling, just like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

add it before `<body>` closing because DOM hasn't got to "**my_image_id**" by the time your relevant script is executed, like:

```
<body>
<img src="xxx.png" width="100px" height="100px" id="my_image_id"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
function doSomething() {
    alert('Image clicked');
 }

 var myImage = document.getElementById('my_image_id');

 myImage.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
</script>
</body>
```

**Added**

```
if (myImage.addEventListener) {
  myImage.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
}
else if(myImage.attachEvent) { // FOR IE
  myImage.attachEvent('onclick', doSomething);
}
else { 
    //
}
```

Comment: Hi tried your code and  works fine in moz and chrome. but ie giving error "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @Sujesh see the added code you need to use attachEvent for IE

Comment: Yeah its working fine, but a small doubt. why we should add the script after the markup? in usual case, if we use "var myImage = document.getElementById('my_image_id'); before, we'll be able to access the image, but why not in this case?

Comment: @Sujesh as i mentioned in answer comment part above, your javascript code var myImage = document.getElementById('my_image_id'); gets executed before the DOM gets to your image tag, as a result of which, it throws error since it could not find element with id 'my_image_id'.. i hope its clear

Comment: @Sujesh: why don't put the code inside `window.onload`? it's better as `window.onload` is for this purpose.

Comment: Thank you all,
I got the concept now. Previously i was doing only inline event handling and i'm new to addEventListener. so there was no problem with the loading. in this case, we can either use "window.onload" as suggested by "Khanh TO" ( we can have the code anywhere inside the <script> tag because we are using window.load ) or as suggested by "Sudhir" but in this case, we have to put the code after the "image" element "<img src="xxx.png" width="100px"height="100px"id="my_image_id "/>"

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function()
{
myImage.addEventListener('click', doSomething, false);
}
```

Comment: working fine in moz and chrome. but ie giving error "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @Sujesh: the reason is `addEventListener` does not work on all browsers (IE uses `attachEvent`). Check my answer